# Parametrizing and reduce in Functional Programming

Tags: functional-programming

I am going through a paper named [*Why functional programming matters*](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/whyfp90.pdf). It begins with an introduction of illustrating the calculation of sum of the numbers in a list .The formulation then emphasizes that this sum can be computed in a recursive manner by summing a number in the list with the sum function of the rest of the list and terms this process as a reduce and then writes that the definition of reduce can be obtained by parametrising  the definition of sum as follow :

```
(reduce f x)  nil = x
(reduce f x) (cons a l)  =  f a ((reduce f x ) l)
```

What I want to know is that do we actually write like this in programs in functional programming or this is just an illustration of a concept ?

The same is my question when it illustrates one more function `doubleaddcons` which can be written as follow:

```
doubleall = reduce doubleandcons nil
```

where `doubleandcons num list = cons (2*num) list`

Is it actually written like this in programs or just an illustration of a concept?

Comment: With languages intended to be purely functional or almost so (OCAML, Haskell, etc), the compiler may well do a fine job of optimizing the functional expression of primitives like `reduce`. In those, yes, you do program like that. But most languages that are imperative with functional features (Python, Ruby, Java 8, Scala, etc.) won't bother. They'll give you a library `reduce` implementation that uses iteration under the hood.

Comment: It's not clear what's puzzling you, but if it's the syntax, the Introduction says "We are following Turner’s language Miranda". Miranda was a precursor to Haskell; the syntax is very similar. If you're wondering whether anyone actually uses higher-order functions like `reduce`, the answer is "all the time".

Comment: Yes, this particular example illustrates the concept of parametrising patterns - in this case, the loop (or recursion) over a list. We do much weirder abstractions than this :-)

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the functional programming world as a whole, but I can offer an example of how such a thing would be written in a common language like JavaScript that supports functional programming to some degree.

```js
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const sum = nums.reduce((x, xs) => x + xs);
console.log(sum);
```

Not sure if that exactly answers your question though. I assumed you were looking for real-world use cases for the functional concept of a reduce.

Comment: Even in JS, we expect empty arrays to sum to `0`.

Comment: To me, the question sounds more like it is about how `reduce` (and things like that) are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The book uses a predecessor to Haskell called Miranda so the examples is functioning code written in that language. I don't know Miranda that well but in Haskell you can write the same in a handful of different ways that might be easier to read for a typical Algol programmer.

In Algol the way of writing in the first style is called multi methods and it's kind of fashionable lately. eg in Perl6:

```perl6
multi factorial(0)      { 1 }
multi factorial(Int $x) { $x * factorial($x - 1) }
```

A middle ground popping up is `match` which is a combination of switch-case and destructuring:

```scm
(define (factorial n)
  (match n
    [0 1]
    [n (* n (factorial (- n 1)))]))
```

Here you see that it is quite similar to the more classical way of writing it in JS:

```js
function factorial (n) {
  return n === 0 ? 
         1 : 
         n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

All the above are just syntactic differences for the same. They mean the same and a compiler that supports all these ways it might compile to the same object code.

For the `doubleall` example it shows features of Miranda like currying. If you apply too few arguments the result is a function that takes the remaining arguments.

```hs
reduce doubleandcons nil [1, 2, 3] 
==> [2, 4, 6]

reduce doubleandcons nil
==> function of arity 1

(reduce doubleandcons nil) [1, 2, 3]
==> [2, 4, 6]
```

While `doubleandcons` is pretty straight forward:

```hs
doubleandcons num list = cons (2*num) list
```

As a JS arrow function it would be

```js
const doubleandcons = (num, list) => cons(2 * num, list)
```

In Miranda (and Haskell) you use parentheses to change the default association. eg. without them around `(2*num)` `cons` would have been given them as separate arguments.